# Remove limit for RestAPI outlook contacts

Tags: rest, outlook

This is a separate question from a previous one that I was advised to ask in a new question. I have a RestAPI contacting outlook to pull back contacts. However, I want to remove the limit to the amount of contacts returned.

My code currently is:

```
client
    .api('/me/contacts')
    .top(8)
    .select('givenName,surname,emailAddresses')
    .orderby('givenName ASC')
    .get((err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        callback(null, err);
      } else {
        contacts = res.value; // store contacts in array for future use
        callback(res.value);
      }
  });
```

I could increase the value in .top(8) to be something rediculous like .top(10000), but is there a way to return all (essentially remove the .top) variable? Tried it but code errors so assuming this is a required field.

Thanks

Comment: Is there anyone interested in more than 8 (or 80?) contacts?? not enough context, (or i am having not enough knowledge about this) is given.

Comment: There would be more interest if using a website that allows you to contact your contacts to invite them to join a group. If you want to contact 1 or 10,000 people from you contact list, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: According to this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#OdataQueryParams) it is optional to include 'top'.   Can you specify more of your code, and the info on "Tried it but code errors " ?